# How to manually detect deadlocks

Tags: locking, deadlock

I understand the concepts of deadlock well enough, but when I'm given a problem like the one below I'm not sure how to go about solving it. I can draw a resource allocation graph, but I'm not sure how to solve it from there.

Is there a better more formal way of solving this?

```
Consider  a  system  with  five  processes,  P1  through P5,  and  five 
resources, R1 through R5. Resource ownership is as follows. 

•  P1 holds R1 and wants R3 
•  P2 holds R2 and wants R1 
•  P3 holds R3 and wants R5 
•  P4 holds R5 and wants R2 
•  P5 holds R4 and wants R2
```

Is this system deadlocked? Justify your answer. 

If  the system is deadlocked, list 
the involved processes.

Comment: Draw a graph where wanting a resouce is an incoming edge, having one is an outgoing node, check for loops.

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate for Programmers as it isn't about code specifically, but a conceptual thing.

Comment: @ColeJohnson This is about an algorithmic problem, I'd leave it here

Comment: @jozefg Exactly. I see algorithms more of a fit for Programmers than SO, but that's just me.